# Is there a server side or cloud-side Windows Defender installation administration tool for admins?

Tags: anti-virus, windows-server-2019

I am considering starting the wide use of Windows Defender antivirus on Windows 10, so I am looking is there a way to get a feedback from machines running Windows 10 Defender?

It would also be nice if WD could be controlled on Windows 10 thru a console, but I presume that is done via Group Policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cloud based look into Windows Defender ATP in conjunction with Azure Enterprise Management.

For on-prem you would use SCCM.

You can also manage everything throught GPO and do the reporting by PowerShell or querying the event log. But I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about these tools. If I understood correctly, SCCM would run on Windows Sever as a package?

Comment: Yes, it needs on-prem infrastructure.